# How to analyze the network traffic with Javafx

Tags: networking, javafx, traffic, analyzer

I'm trying to intercept the http calls which are generated during page loading. In other words, I would to realize a network traffic analyzer like the Firefox Firebug Net Panel.

Is it possible in Javafx?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory%28java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory%29)

Read [A new era for Java Protocol Handlers](http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/dm_protocolHandlers/java_protocol.pdf) to understand the background for this.

Answer assumes you are using the standard WebView implementation or the java.net.URL class for networking and not some custom method.

A code sample for this would take me some time.  The recommended approach is to follow the instructions provided in my answer.  I'll put together a code sample in a few days if I have time and the question asker or nobody else has provided a sample.

Comment: Ok got it. But my problem is that I want to manage and process all the http connections coming from a single url. As example consider the case you want all the network responses coming from the url google.com. I mean what I need is something like the network panel in firebug or the inspect element in chrome. In these applications you can find all the responses comining from the loaded url in the browser. I would have a similar behavior using java and javafx. Could you please give me some code example showing your solution?